# Python create union of results from function applied to elements in a set

Tags: python, set, union

I am trying to create a set that contains all the results as returned by a function which is applied to each element in a set. The following code snippet hopefully clarifies:

```
results = set()    
for node in nodes:
    results = set.union(results, foo(node))
```

Although the code accomplishes what I want, I am sure it can be rewritten much better and more concise. As I have to repeat this construct several times, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
results = set()    
for node in nodes:
    results.update(foo(node))
```

or

```
results = set.union(*[foo(node) for node in nodes])
```

If `nodes` can be empty, then use this to make sure it doesn't throw an exception:

```
results = set.union(set(), *[foo(node) for node in nodes])
```

Comment: Your second solution is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Although I was aware of set.union(*x), I did not know if and how it could be applied when a function had to be applied first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is OK, except you can use `|=` operator for set union:

```
results = set()    
for node in nodes:
    results |= set(foo(node))
```

Or you can gather all results in a list and cast it to set once in the end (if you don't expect huge amounts of data)

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `reduce`

```
results = reduce(lambda x,y: set.union(x,y), [foo(x) for x in nodes])
```

Comment: This creates many temporary sets which eumiro's answer avoids.

Comment: @Max it does not. see the implementation, http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce . However, I agree eumiro's second solution is more elegant